# No Image Attachments Found in site.com error msg

Tags: lightning-aura-components, attachment, images, site.com, admin

I created a public site with community, however the image (using lightning image slider) from the different tabs aren't showing for public users. My images are in a files folder, I enabled chat for guest users and from Site's "Public Access Settings" gave read only permission set to the Parent object (document, not sure about this!). I keep getting the error msg "No Image Attachments Found" My images are normal png files. Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution to the above issue.
1st. You need to make sure the notes &attachments related list is available on the page layout for that spcific object.
2nd. Select a related single component from lightning
3rd. Make sure the file is shared via the customer access toggle, enable 'Customer access'.